# Divide the values in textboxes and produce the value in a 3rd textbox

Tags: c#

I am trying to Divide two values that are in 2 different textboxes and have the result show up in a 3rd textbox. Here is the code I have so far:

```
private void Divide()
{
  int val1, val2;
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mergeSortTime.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectionSortTime.Text))
  {
    int.TryParse(mergeSortTime.Text, out val1);
    int.TryParse(selectionSortTime.Text, out val2);
    resetTimeDisplay.Text = (val1 / val2).ToString();
  }
}
```

and I call the Method here:

```
private void selectionSortButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

  selectionSortButton.Enabled = false;
  button1.Location = resetButton.Location;
  button1.Visible = true;
  InitializeForm();
  sw.Start();
  bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
  while (bgWorker.IsBusy)
    Application.DoEvents();
  idList.SelectionSort();
  if (!bgWorkCancelled)
    DisplayIDList(displayDGV);
  sw.Stop();
  TimeSpan ts = sw.Elapsed;
  string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:0}" + "." + "{1:0}",ts.Seconds, ts.Milliseconds);
  selectionSortTime.Text = elapsedTime;
  mergeSortButton.Enabled = false;
  quickSortButton.Enabled = false;
  resetButton.Location = button1.Location;
  button1.Visible = false;
  resetButton.Visible = true;
  Divide();
}
```

how it works right now is I input a number into a totally separate textbox and generate a list of unordered values. I then have 2 buttons that use 2 different ways of sorting and next to them I have a display showing how long it took to sort the values. the 2 display values I need to divide. It's giving me an error that says: "Attempted to divide by zero", I've tried debugging the code and saw that val1 and val2 both have a value of 0, so the error is obviously correct? but `mergeSortTime.Text` and `selectionSortTime.Text` both have the correct values as well.

Anyone mind sharing some insight?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you really want to do is:

```
private void Divide()
 {
   double val1 = 0.0;
   double val2 = 0.0;
   double reset = 0.0;
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mergeSortTime.Text) &&  !string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectionSortTime.Text))
   {
      //Assuming the value entered on the textboxes are numeric the second textbox is greater than 0.
      val1 = double.Parse(mergeSortTime.Text);
      val2 = double.Parse(selectionSortTime.Text);
      //To make sure that val2 is not equal to 0 before the calculation
      if(val2 != 0)
     {
     reset = val1/val2;
     resetTimeDisplay.Text = reset.ToString();
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay. I just switched my code to the above and I get the error: "Input string was not in a correct format" on `int.Parse(mergeSortTime.Text)` I believe I've gotten that same error on other approaches I've taken.

Comment: also I appreciate the help your giving me!

Comment: The possible reason why you receive this error is because you entered a non numeric value on one or all the textboxes.  Make sure you enter only numeric value.  Also make sure the value you entered on the second textbox is not equal to 0.  Otherwise, you'll receive a Divide by 0 exception.

Comment: Okay, the value shouldn't be a non numeric value. the format of the values are going to be like so: "0.0" the first 0 being seconds and the 2nd being miliseconds.

Comment: Instead of integer, you probably need float or double.  double val1 = 0.0 and double val2 = 0.0 (these numeric are just initialization).  I just modified the code.  The integer will ignore any value after the 0.  For example if you have 0.3, the integer will see only 0.

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much!